# Configure Log4Net in web application

Tags: c#, log4net

I have this code and the config file below:

```
ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));
log.Debug("Testing");
```

`TestProj` directory is not created and if I create it, no `TestLog.txt` file, no log ... nothing.

Any idea?

Thanks,

**The config file**

```xml
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />

<log4net debug="true">
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\\TestProj\\TestLog.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
</root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Does the web application have permissions to create directory and file?

Comment: It's on my dev machine > full permission

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/using-log4net-web-applications

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You need to call the `Configure`function of the `XmlConfigurator`

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Either call before your first loggin call or in your Global.asax like this:

```
protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
   log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
```

Comment: OK that's work :) Now I have to configure the file to see in the log what I want

Comment: If you are using a Web project you may have to do new item and add the Global.asax file, because it doesn't exist by default.  You should also immediately log something.  log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();  log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType); log.Debug("Setup in Application_Start.");

Comment: Does this solution imply (which I hope) that the logger is there for all sessions of this web application?  It certainly seems to work that way for me, but is it a bad idea? e.g. Globals.cs contans    
  public static ILog Logger { get; set; } = LogManager.GetLogger("LOGGER");

and it is referenced everywhere as 
Globals.Logger?.Debug(LabelMsg.Text);
or through a variable in some class to shorten:
    private ILog Logger { get; set; } = Globals.Logger;

Answer (score 24):

Another way to do this would be to add this line to the assembly info of the web application:

```
// Configure log4net using the .config file
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

Similar to Shriek's.

Comment: This will only work in "normal" applications, but not with an web application.

Comment: @shriek: I am not sure you are right. This attribute is used to configure the XmlConfigurator without calling one of the Configure methods. It is correct that `Watch=True` don't have much value because a change in the web.config always causes a restart of the web application

Comment: @hwcverwe: I just had this very same problem yesterday, the Attribute was there but the logger didn't do anything. Only after calling the `Configure` Method before the first call to the logger it worked. (This was for a WCF service)

Comment: @shriek: +1 for your solution because you are making sure log4net has called the Configure method before you start logging. The assembly attribute is in some situations not working properly. But still I have also WCF services which are logging properly so it is not a fact websites and WCF services cannot use the assembly attribute.

Comment: I use the assembly attribute in a web application and it works. The key is to instantiate the logger from the same project that has the assembly attribute (i.e. in Global.asax for example). See "When should I log my first message" in [FAQ](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html)

Comment: Can you add an assembly attribute in a web application in MSVS 10?

Answer (score 11):

1: Add the following line into the AssemblyInfo class

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

2: Make sure you don't use `.Net Framework 4 Client Profile` as `Target Framework` (I think this is OK on your side because otherwise it even wouldn't compile)

3: Make sure you log very early in your program. Otherwise, in some scenarios, it will not be initialized properly (read more on [log4net FAQ](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#first-log)).

So log something during application startup in the Global.asax

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Global));
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Log.Info("Startup application.");
    }
}
```

4: Make sure you have permission to create files and folders on the given path (if the folder itself also doesn't exist)

5: The rest of your given information looks ok

Comment: @Default See "When should I log my first message" in [FAQ](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html)

Answer (score 2):

often this is due to missing permissions. The windows account the local IIS Application Pool is running with may not have the permission to write to the applications directory. You could create a directory somewhere, give everyone permission to write in it and point your log4net config to that directory. If then a log file is created there, you can modify the permissions for your desired log directory so that the app pool can write to it.

Another reason could be an uninitialized log4net. In a winforms app, you usually configure log4net upon application start. In a web app, you can do this either dynamically (in your logging component, check if you can create a specific Ilog logger using its name, if not -> call configure()) or again upon application start in global.asax.cs.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the similar issue. Logs were not creating.

Please check logger attribute name should match with your LogManager.GetLogger("name")

```
<logger name="Mylog">
      <level value="All"></level>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </logger>



private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger("Mylog");
```