# Statement executed but logfile not created. What went wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, log4net

I followed logging instructions given [here](http://www.justinrhinesmith.com/blog/2008/05/12/quick-and-easy-log4net-setup/):

I created a Assembly.cs that has this the following:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

This is my web.config file:

```
<configuration>

    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net"
                 type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
<log4net>
        <appender name="FileAppender"
                  type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
            <file value="C:\Users\SOIS\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\DummyPharmacy\logfile.txt" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] – %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="DEBUG" />
            <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
        </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

My connection class where I use logger has this:
using log4net;

```
public class Connection
{
  private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Connection));
```

The debug shows execution of the logging. No file created in my folder though. What went wrong?

[image: Execution]

My output file has this:

```
log4net:ERROR Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' 
in the application's .config file.Check your .config file 
for the <log4net> and <configSections> elements. The configuration
section should look like: <section name="log4net"
type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
```

I have made a separate log4net.config file. Because editing the existing one does not allow me to define a  element.

Comment: Are you sure that your application does have permissions to write to the folder C:\Users\SOIS\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\DummyPharmacy?
Check the output during application execution, log4net should put any error information into the output console.

Comment: @GeorgySmirnov Thanks. Checked output. Edited my question with the error.

Comment: That was so long ago:( I would suggest configure log4net in global.asax

Comment: @GeorgySmirnov

Where do I place this?

`[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile="log4net.config", Watch = true)]`

Comment: You wouldn't need to do that, just follow the first answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204171/configure-log4net-in-web-application

Comment: `void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e){log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();}` That was in place all along. I just cant figure out where the issue is!

Comment: you mean that you configure log4net in two places (assembly.cs and global.asax)?

Comment: Yes, though I don't think anything is calling Assembly.cs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you didn't tell log4net to read config from your `log4net.config` file in your assembly attribute:

see the [Configuration Attributes](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) in official document:

```
// Configure log4net using the .config file
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]
// This will cause log4net to look for a configuration file
// called TestApp.exe.config in the application base
// directory (i.e. the directory containing TestApp.exe)
// The config file will be watched for changes.
```

Change it to following should work:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile="log4net.config",Watch=true)]
```

Or if you prefer a single .config file, then keep the attribute and move the configruations from `log4net.config` to `Web.config`.

Comment: I did this in my Assembly.cs. It did not work. However, I need to add that  this was a file I just created because the tutorial needed it. Anywhere else I should be placing this?

Comment: The tutorial suggest you to put the log4net section in Web.config, not a separate file. In that case you don't need to modify the attribute.

Comment: I edited my answer with the current status. It's still executing but not logging.