# Log4net is not logging any data into the file while debugging

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I am using log4net in my C# application to log the steps while the application is running. While debugging I don't see anything logged into the file. Below is the config file.

```
<log4net>
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%thread] %level - %message%newline%exception"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\Users\dv\Desktop\Logs\API.log"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="100KB"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{ISO8601} [%thread] %level - %message%newline%exception"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="INFO"/>
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
  </root>
 </log4net>
```

And below is how I log.

```
if (jrGet == null)  
{
    jrForCore = mergeJrForUpdate(fromJaxStrain, new JrNumberGet());
    path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PostResourceString"];
    var url = await CreateProductAsync(path, jrForCore);
    logger.Info("Created : " + fromJaxStrain.Barcode);
}
```

Comment: What is `jrGet`? Is it null?

Comment: Does the application log when you do not debug or use a release build?

Comment: Since the logs are stored in the user directory - is it possible that it can't write to that location without running with elevated permissions?

Comment: @mason jrGet is null

Comment: How did you create logger ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to track down log4net problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756125/how-to-track-down-log4net-problems)

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd We never released it. when I debug it is not logging, which I expect to happen

Comment: The loglines might not appear instantly. Start the application, let it start completely, close it properly. Check the log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure Log4Net in web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204171/configure-log4net-in-web-application)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're missing:

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Must be in there somewhere when things startup to tell it to read the config file.